# Sound Waves Moving Large Objects?

Tags: acoustics, levitation

I recently read an article over using sound to move/levitate objects in mid air. Which is basically using sound to go against/defy gravity. For Many years Physicists have been able to move smaller objects with sound but could this be done with **larger objects**?

Let me give you an example of what i mean; We have a 5'-5'-5' cube of concrete. This maybe weighs around 4000 Lbs. Now note from the information i had gathered you can levitate a droplet of water with around 24000 Hz, around the same pitch as a dog whistle. But what i couldn't find was the decibel frequency.

So does this mean that it wouldn't be possible with humans in the immediate vicinity? 150 Decibels is enough to bust your eardrums and 200 to rupture your lungs, more than likely killing you. Now, even if it will kill you, is it still possible?

Below are some links to websites i checked that have experimented on small scale objects

If i made any errors feel free to correct me, Thanks in advance

[Researchers demonstrate acoustic levitation of a large sphere](https://phys.org/news/2016-08-acoustic-levitation-large-sphere.html)

[Sound waves can be used to levitate and move objects](https://www.washingtonpost.com/national/health-science/sound-waves-can-be-used-to-levitate-and-move-objects-study-says/2013/07/15/4d808a5e-eb15-11e2-8023-b7f07811d98e_story.html?noredirect=on&utm_term=.03df2036a109)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *power density* of sound waves is really low. This means that while you might be able to move small, light things around with loudspeakers that are playing really loud, moving big stuff around requires sound waves produced by high explosives. So this is not the sort of thing worth experimenting with- unless of course you enjoy blowing things up.

Comment: When you say high explosives how big are we talking. Could it possible be on the level of atomic or is that a bit overkill?

Comment: overkill. a half stick of dynamite will lift a car off the ground, in the process also performing other irreversible types of work on it... ;-)